# Writing while (*/that a variable not equal to a double) loop

Tags: java

I want the below code to loop everytime the user enter a non-number input 
ex if the user enters a (p) the code should show " please enter a valid number and take the user back to" enter the first number "

But if the user entered a number in the first number but a non-number in the sec I want the code to take the user to " enter the sec number not "enter the first number "

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        double s1 = 0;
        double s2 = 0;

        while (true) {

            try {
                s1 = Double.valueOf(getinput("enter first number"));
                s2 = Double.valueOf(getinput("enter sec number"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("please enter a Valid number");

            }

            continue;
        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Use two loops, one to get the first number, another to get the second number,

Comment: You could write a function `double getDouble(String prompt)` that does not return until the user has entered a valid input. Then call that 2x

Answer (score 3):

You can use two loops, one for each number, and go further when your Double is not null anymore

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double s1 = null;
    Double s2 = null;

    while (true) {

        while(s1 == null){
          try {
            s1 = Double.valueOf(getinput("enter first number"));
          } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("please enter a Valid number");
          }
        }

       while(s2 == null){
          try {
            s2 = Double.valueOf(getinput("enter first number"));
          } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("please enter a Valid number");
          }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The `continue;` is unnecessary at the end of the loop block.

Answer (score 2):

You will need two loops.

```
double s1 = 0;
double s2 = 0;

boolean s1Valid = false;
boolean s2Valid = false;

while (!s1Valid) {
    try {
        s1 = Double.valueOf(getinput("enter first number"));
        s1Valid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // you should declare exceptions as specifically as possible
        System.out.println("please enter a Valid number");
    }
}

while (!s2Valid) {
    try {
        s2 = Double.valueOf(getinput("enter second number"));
        s2Valid = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("please enter a Valid number");
    }
}
```